# Tangent line limit of a slope

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

I want to find the equation of the tangent line to $x(t)=2\cos(t)\cos(2t)$, $y(t)=2\sin(t)-\sin(2t)$ at $t=0$.

I used this site https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/tangent-line-calculator/?ft=t&f=2cos%28t%29cos%282t%29&g=%272sin%28t%29-sin%282t%29&px=0

According to it, the equation of the tangent line is $y=0$. Looking at the solution, I noticed that to find the slope, the limit is taken. Is it correct to do so, or should I just plug the values and say that the slope is undefined, so the tangent line doesn't exist?

A limit tells how the function behaves near a point, not at it. The tangent line should be found at the point, not near it.

Is there a reason for the taking of the limit to be justified?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with OP that the tangent line should be found at the point in question, and a justification is required for finding the slope at a nearby point and then taking the limit of that slope as that nearby point approaches the point in question.

Let $P$ be the point $(x(0), y(0)) = (2,0)$.  If you graph the curve, you will find that it has a cusp at $P$, so it is not clear to me that the there is a line that should be called the tangent line at $P$.  Nevertheless, the following calculation gives the line that is tangent to both sides of the cusp at $P$.

The usual way to find the slope of the tangent line at $P$ is to find the slope of the line through $P$ and a nearby point $Q$ on the curve, and then take the limit of this slope as $Q$ approaches $P$.  The nearby point $Q$ will be $(x(t), y(t))$ for $t \ne 0$, and the slope of the line through $P$ and $Q$ is
$$
\frac{y(t) - 0}{x(t) - 2} = \frac{2\sin(t) - \sin(2t)}{2\cos(t)\cos(2t) - 2}.
$$
So the tangent slope we want is
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2\sin(t) - \sin(2t)}{2\cos(t)\cos(2t) - 2}.
$$
By L'Hopital's rule, we can find this limit by computing
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\cos(t) - \cos(2t)}{6\sin^3(t)-5\sin(t)}.
$$
This is the same as the limit on the site referred to by OP, but now a justification has been given for computing that limit.

Comment: does it work for y=cos(x)^x at x=pi/2?

Comment: For $0 < x < \pi/2$ this means $y = e^{x \ln(\cos x)}$; at $x = \pi/2$, $y = 0$.  You'd have to use a limit as $x \to \pi/2^-$, but yes, the same approach could be used.  The limit is quite a bit harder to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the step where $M(t_0)$ has been derived. One can observe that $M(t_0)$ is a rational function whose denominator is $0$ when $t = 0$. So, $M(0)$ does not exist. This is what justifies taking the limit as $t \to 0$. Taking the limit allows you to apply L'Hopital's rule, which requires some more justification than I've given here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

At the point under consideration the slope is continuous, passing from negative to positive via zero.

So at this point the tangent is the x-axis, $y=0$. ( Like a corner of the astroid on x-axis).